# What SQL query will replace nth character(s) in QGIS DBManager?

Tags: qgis, sql, timemanager, database

I have a table with a date/time column.  The symbols separating the date need to be changed in order for it to work with the TimeManager plugin.

Eg. 2016:08:13 08:41:20 to 2016/08/13 08:41:20

The column name is 'datetimeor' and the table is 'ba396'

Comment: If you check your layer info in db manager, is your column type a datetime or a text (like char, varchar...)?

Comment: varchar (254)..........................

Comment: Welcome to gis.stackexchange! Please note that a good question on this site is expected to show some degree of research on your part, i.e. what you have tried and - if applicable - code so far. For more info, you can check our [faq].

Answer (score 1):

In pure SQL you could convert your varchar field to a datetime using something like this :

```
CAST(SUBSTRING('datetimeor',1,4) + '-' + SUBSTRING('datetimeor',6,2) + '-' +
SUBSTRING('datetimeor',9,2) + 'T' + SUBSTRING('datetimeor',12,2) + ':' + 
SUBSTRING('datetimeor',15,2) + ':' + SUBSTRING('datetimeor',18,2) as datetime)
```

This would have to be tested on your system, i believe it depends on your database server type and version, etc.

Comment: That's a bit more complicated than I expected.  I figured out how to export the date in the proper format so I don't need this.  Thank you for your help.  I'm not sure if I should accept this answer due to the circumstances.